How can I detect azure cloud defender recommendations early?
Is there a good way to prevent defender for cloud recommendations/warnings before doing changes?
Defender for DevOps usually deals with SAST scanning on repos, but the warnings I'm interested in blocking are terraform changes that modifies/creates resources in Azure that in turn leads to defender for cloud warnings.
For example

Using Storage account with SAS tokens
No firewall set in SQL Server instance
Function App should only be accessible over HTTPS

Context/Background:
We use Terraform code checked in git to configure and deploy hundreds of instances of SQL, appservers, in-house applications in docker containers and others in Azure. The idea is to shift security left and fail the TF build pipelines instead of chasing down teams after defender findings.

The best option is to prevent resources being deployed with insecure configurations. You can use Azure Policies for that. There are many built-in Azure Policies, for example:

Function app slots should only be accessible over HTTPS
Storage accounts should prevent shared key access

and if there is no built-in policy you can create your own custom policy.
With Azure Policies in place you cannot create or modify resources that violate a policy using any automation or using the Azure Portal. If resources are deployed using ARM or bicep templates using TF Build pipelines those pipelines will fail if the conditions are not met.
